# cannot find symbol class newRequestQueue in Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I get this error

```
Error:(42, 38) error: cannot find symbol class newRequestQueue
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

on line:

```
RequestQueue queue=new Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the problem. `new` should not be present in the last line.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10691184)

Comment: @ArthurKorchagin How does this not provide an answer? Compare the line in the answer and the question - the `new` needed to be removed. This isn't something we should delete from review.